# How to restrict re-uploading after uploading of file using singed url in google cloud store in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage

I am able to create [siged url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) for uploading file to [google cloud store](https://cloud.google.com/storage) with help of example given at

https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/generateV4UploadSignedUrl.js

```
var {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage')

var storage = new Storage({
    projectId: "projectId",
    credentials: {
        client_email: "clientEmail",
        private_key: "privateKey"
    }
})

var generateUploadSignedUrl = async function(bucketName, remoteFilename, expires) {
    const options = {
        version: 'v4',
        action: 'write',
        expires: expires,
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
      }
    var url = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(remoteFilename).getSignedUrl(options)
    return url
}
```

I am able to use singed url for uploading file.
But I want to put restriction that after uploading I should not be able to upload again. How can I add such policy?

I gave look on [policy-document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document) but could not find relevent condition for restricting re-upload.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do it.

If you use gsutil, you can use the flag -n. As [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options) documentation says, "When specified, existing files or objects at the destination will not be overwritten. Any items that are skipped by this option will be reported as being skipped".

On the other hand, using the client library, there is nothing like that. Nevertheless, first, you can check if [the file exists](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#exists), and if not, copy it.

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/generateV4SignedPolicy.js can this be useful?

Comment: If you want to use it as example on how to authenticate with V4 signing, you can take it, but something to take into account is that V4 is on beta and has limited support. I recommend you to check other options like this https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/uploadFile.js